# jquery crashing on IE7 when calling functions

Tags: jquery, crash, internet-explorer-7, nyromodal

I'm developing a tool here in my work and i have to use the IE7 to do it... So everithing was fine but in a specific page that loads a huge amount of data from a db(2000 rows from oracle) the JS is not working well.
When i Use this piece of code 
`<script type="text/javascript">
('input#search').quicksearch('#Table1 tbody tr');
</script>`
 its doing fine but when e add any other functions to it the jquery stops responding on IE .

Here is my Jquery declaration

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Css/style.css"/><!--Table Style-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css"/> <!--Jquery UI elements-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.quicksearch.js"></script><!--Table Search Scripts-->


<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nyroModal.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.nyroModal.custom.js"></script>
<!--[if IE 6]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.nyroModal-ie6.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

any help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the dollar `$`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('input#search').quicksearch('#Table1 tbody tr');
</script>
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer and i'm pretty sure thats is not the problem. I fixed the code above and still not working...Remembering my page have huge amount of data and just crashes on IE, in firebug not problem is found...